# I want to completely flatten/remove some pdf text/objects outline in the pdf document I am working with using iText or any tools programmatically

Tags: object, pdf, itext, adobe, flatten

I am having an issue with a pdf that seems to have irregular pdf objects which doesn't allow me to highlight the pdf text that I want. Has anyone ran into this issue? I would like a programmatic issue if possible but have not been able to find anything else online myself. Anything helps, thanks!

[When I try to highlight text in a field (to copy text)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atUdy.png)

[image: PDF object Outlines]

[Desired result, after objects have been flattened or fixed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8A58p.png)

I've tried to use flattening via iText and Adobe, but I am not sure if flattening will help with this.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have a corrupted copy the master document has no problems see
https://www.tax.ny.gov/pdf/current_forms/it/it204ip_fill_in.pdf Last modified D:20231102131743-04'00'

[image]